# If Value null do something

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to display a date. But sometimes this completion_date value comes undefined/null.

How do I say if null write `No Date` on the table? Whats the proper way to avoid messy HTML?

```
<td>{{ticket.COMPLETION_DATE | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
```

Comment: May be `<td>{{ticket.COMPLETION_DATE == null ? 'No Date' : ticket.COMPLETION_DATE}}</td>`

Comment: Generally I do something like `obj.var || "When Undefined"`  as a shorthand to what mamun has suggested. But if you are nesting deeper, I prefer lodash `_.get(obj,"a.b.c","Default")`

Answer (score 0):

May be wrap in ng-if as an alternative. Not sure if that satisfies your need to not be messy though.

```
<td ng-if="ticket.COMPLETION_DATE">{{ticket.COMPLETION_DATE | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
<td ng-if="!ticket.COMPLETION_DATE">No Date</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a ternary operator and wrap your filter on *truthy* condition. Here is a demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.t = new Date();
  $scope.t2 = null;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <span>{{t ? (t | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') : 'No Date'}}</span>
  <hr>
  <span>{{t2 ? (t2 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') : 'No Date'}}</span>

</div>
```

(You might want a more complicated *if statement*, if you want to accept `0`, since it's a falsy value)